# MD5 File Hashing - match Delphi output with PHP md5_file function

Tags: php, delphi, hash, md5

I'm currently using this code for md5 hashing in Delphi 7:

```
function MD5(const fileName : string) : string;
var
  idmd5 : TIdHashMessageDigest5;
  fs : TFileStream;
begin
  idmd5 := TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create;
  fs := TFileStream.Create(fileName, fmOpenRead OR fmShareDenyWrite) ;
  try
    result := idmd5.AsHex(idmd5.HashValue(fs)) ;
  finally
    fs.Free;
    idmd5.Free;
  end;
end;
```

and I'm trying to get the output the same as the PHP function

```
md5_file()
```

I've had a look around and common problems seem to be encoding and not padding with zeroes, but I don't know how to do either of these using TIdHashMessageDigest5 or whether they are already done in the function.

If anyone has any functions they use for this it'd be very appreciated!

Or possibly a way of changing the php function to match the Indy one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compare your results with:

- `md5(file_get_contents( ))` in PHP
- `hash("md5", )` from the [PHP hash framework extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.hash.php)
- the command line programs md5(1) aka
  md5sum(1)

If all but one agree what the sum is, then you know where to dig.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you didn't give a Delphi version number, but if you're on D2007 or later you might want to check out [this article.](http://wiert.wordpress.com/2009/12/11/delphi-md5-the-messagedigest_5-unit-has-been-there-since-delphi-2007/)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning my article!

--jeroen

Comment: The article Mason points to got updated today:
Edit: 20091223:  Since Delphi 7.01, Indy has provided the unit IdHashMessageDigest which also does md5, see the comments.