# Finding this function in delphi MD5(tmpBuffer, sizeof(opera_salt) + DES_KEY_SZ, hashSignature1);

Tags: delphi

I am porting opera recovery from already existing C++ code

> http://pastebin.com/ViPf0yn6

I struck at this function

```
MD5(tmpBuffer, sizeof(opera_salt) + DES_KEY_SZ, hashSignature1);
```

Where can I get that MD5 unit?

Comment: See these two questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447985/file-md5-checksum http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952929/md5-file-hashing-match-delphi-output-with-php-md5file-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

steve0, the code in your link reference to the md5 openssl implementation, you can find the original declaration of the MD5 function used in the code in this [link](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/md5.html#SYNOPSIS)

```
 unsigned char *MD5(const unsigned char *d, unsigned long n, unsigned char *md);
```

you can use the [`MessageDigest_5`](http://wiert.wordpress.com/2009/12/11/delphi-md5-the-messagedigest_5-unit-has-been-there-since-delphi-2007/) (since Delphi 2007) unit to calculate the md5 for a buffer or the `TIdHashMessageDigest5` class from the [indy](http://www.indyproject.org/) components.